# How do I proceed with the rest of the function to keep updating my message box in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to do a message box to warns the user in my UI that they will be moved to the homepage after 10 seconds, codes are as following:

```
from tkinter import *
import warnings
import random
import time
import sqlite3
from tkinter import simpledialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import winsound

##-------------Frames setup--------------------------
class VendingApp(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(Home)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        #Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one.
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

####-----------------------Home page---------------------------
class Home(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
##-----------------------fuctions-----------------------------------
        def clicked(a):
            if (a.x <=1920) and (a.y<=1080):
                master.switch_frame(Store)
                print ("1")
            else:
                 None
            None


##----------------setup------------------------------------------
        self._images = list()

        img_banner = Image.open("pic/banner.jpg")
        img_banner = img_banner.resize((400,100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        banner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_banner)
        self._images.append(banner)



##---------------------Top frame Home------------------------------------
        topFrame = Frame(self,width = 1920, height = 1080)
        topFrame.pack()

        canvasM = Canvas(topFrame,height=1080, width=1920)
        canvasM['highlightthickness'] = 0
        canvasM.pack()

        body = canvasM.create_rectangle(0, 0,1920,1080, fill = 'gray95')
        mylabel = canvasM.create_text((960, 390),font=("Purisa", 40), text="Touch anywhere to continue")
        canvasM.tag_bind(body,"<Button>",clicked)
        canvasM.tag_bind(mylabel,"<Button>",clicked)

#-------------------------Store page--------------------------------------------------------------
class Store(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)


        def timeset():
            global time
            time = 15

        def active(event):
            global  time
            time = 15
            print (time)


        def timeout():
            global  time
            if time >= 10:
                time -= 1
                master.after(1000, timeout)
            elif time <= 10 and time > 0:
                askuser()
                time -= 1
                master.after(1000, timeout)
            elif time <= 0:
                master.switch_frame(Home)
            print(time)

        def askuser():
            ask = messagebox.showinfo('Are you there?','Returning to home page in ' + (str(time)) + ' seconds. \n please touch the screen to continue using the app')


        self._images = list()

        img_banner = Image.open("pic/banner.jpg")
        img_banner = img_banner.resize((400, 100), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        banner = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_banner)
        self._images.append(banner)

        ##---------------------pictures and filters Store------------------------------------
        PicFrame = Frame(self, width=400, height=100)
        PicFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
        PicFrame.grid_propagate(False)


        canvas_for_banner = Canvas(PicFrame, height=100, width=400 ) # banner image
        canvas_for_banner.pack(anchor = N)
        canvas_for_banner['highlightthickness'] = 0
        canvas_for_banner.grid_propagate(False)
        canvas_for_banner.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=banner)
 ##---------------------------------Midd store-------------------
        FilterFrame =Frame(self, width=400, height=930, relief = RAISED, bd =1)
        FilterFrame.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
        FilterFrame.pack_propagate(0)



        Ava_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Availability", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        Ava_title.pack(pady = (100,0))
        self.stock_yes = IntVar()
        self.stock_no = IntVar()

        check_ava = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Avaliable', variable = self.stock_yes, font = 20, command = None)
        check_ava.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_unava = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Unavaliable', font = 20, variable = self.stock_no, command = None)
        check_unava.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady = 10)



        gend_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Gender", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        gend_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.boi = IntVar()
        self.girl = IntVar()

        check_boi = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Male', font = 20, variable = self.boi)
        check_boi.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady = 10)

        cehck_girl = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Female', font = 20, variable = self.girl)
        cehck_girl.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)



        Class_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Uniform class", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        Class_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.formal = IntVar()
        self.sport = IntVar()

        check_formal = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Formal', font = 20, variable = self.formal)
        check_formal.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_sport = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Sport', font = 20, variable = self.sport)
        check_sport.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)



        type_title = Label(FilterFrame, text = "Type", font = ('Helvetica', 20, 'bold'))
        type_title.pack(pady = (30,0))
        self.shirts = IntVar()
        self.pants = IntVar()
        self.misc  = IntVar()

        check_shirts = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Shirts', font = 20, variable = self.shirts)
        check_shirts.pack( anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_pants = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Pants', font = 20, variable = self.pants)
        check_pants.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)

        check_misc = Checkbutton(FilterFrame, text = 'Misc', font = 20, variable = self.misc)
        check_misc.pack(anchor = 'w', padx = 30, pady =10)




##------------------------\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\---------------------------------------------

        MidFrame = Frame(self,width = 1520, height = 1030, relief = SUNKEN, bd = 2)
        MidFrame.grid(row = 0, column = 1, rowspan = 2)
        MidFrame.grid_propagate(False)

        store_canvas = Canvas(MidFrame, width = 1520, height = 1030)
        store_canvas.pack()
        store_canvas.pack_propagate(0)



        frames = []
        frame_order = []
        num = 1

        for x in range(4):
            frames.append([])
            for y in range(4):
                frames[x].append(0)

        for x in range(4):
            for y in range(4):
                frames[x][y] = Frame(store_canvas, width=1520 / 4, height=1030 / 4, bd = 2, relief = SOLID)
                frames[x][y].grid(row=y, column=x)
                frames[x][y].pack_propagate(False)
                frame_order.append(frames[x][y])

        for frame in frame_order:
            Label(frame, text=num, anchor='nw').pack( side = 'left')
            num += 1




        ##------------------------\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\---------------------------------------------


        BottomFrame = Frame(self,width = 1920, height = 50, bd = 2, relief = RAISED)
        BottomFrame.grid(row = 2, column =0, columnspan = 2)
        BottomFrame.pack_propagate(False)

        help_btn = Button(BottomFrame, width = 5, height = 3, text = '?', image = None)
        help_btn.pack(side = 'right')


        master.bind("<Button>",active)


        timeset()
        timeout()



#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = VendingApp()
    #Renames the TITLE of the window
    root.title("Vending machine")
    root.geometry("1920x1080")
    root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
    root.resizable(False, False)
    root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the whole program 'freezes' every time the msg box pop up and unless the user confirms 'ok' then the function will pick up where it left off. Is there any way to keep the function going, hence the number in the msg box will update according to the time remaining? Am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Is there another module for this all along and I am just using the wrong module for the task? Please go easy on me, I am still learning. All responses all much appreciated.

Comment: There is far too much code here. Can you express this problem in a much shorter program?

Comment: You should not use `messagebox.showinfo()` if you don't want the dialog to block the application.  Use `Toplevel()` instead, i.e. create the dialog yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`messagebox` will pause the further execution until it receives an input. To prevent this you can try the following

- Use `threading`

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from threading import Thread

def msgbox():

    def _display():
        messagebox.showinfo('Info','Self distruction after 2 seconds')

    Thread(target=_display).start()
    root.after(2000,root.destroy)

root=Tk()

button=Button(root,text='Run',command=msgbox)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

- Create your own info box using `Toplevel` (the below example will create a replica (*sort of*) of standard windows info box)

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class InfoBox(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,title,message,parent=None):
        Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.bell()
        self.transient(self.master)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(bg='white')
        top_frame=Frame(self,bd=0,bg=self['bg'])
        top_frame.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=20)
        bottom_frame=Frame(self,bd=0)
        bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')
        self.info_icon=Canvas(top_frame,width=36,height=36
            ,bg=self['bg'],bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
        self.info_icon.create_oval(0,0,30,30,fill='#0077be',outline='#0077be')
        self.info_icon.create_text(15,16,text='i',font=('',18),fill='white')
        self.info_icon.pack(side='left',padx=(20,0),anchor='center')
        self.label=Label(top_frame,text=message,bg=self['bg'])
        self.label.pack(padx=(1,20),pady=5,anchor='center')
        self.ok_button=ttk.Button(bottom_frame,text='OK',
            state='active',command=self.destroy)
        self.ok_button.pack(anchor='e',padx=15,pady=10)
        self.update()
        center_x=self.winfo_screenwidth()//2-self.winfo_width()//2
        center_y=self.winfo_screenheight()//2-self.winfo_height()//2
        self.geometry(f'+{center_x}+{center_y}')

def msgbox():
    InfoBox('Info','Self distruction after 2 seconds')
    root.after(2000,root.destroy)

root=Tk()

button=Button(root,text='Run',command=msgbox)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE**

Stacking is automatically prevented

```py
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class InfoBox(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        self.exists=False

    def call(self,title,message,parent=None):
        if self.exists:
            self._destroy()
        Toplevel.__init__(self,parent)
        self.bell()
        self.transient(self.master)
        self.title(title)
        self.config(bg='white')
        top_frame=Frame(self,bd=0,bg=self['bg'])
        top_frame.pack(side='top',fill='x',pady=20)
        bottom_frame=Frame(self,bd=0)
        bottom_frame.pack(side='bottom',fill='x')
        self.info_icon=Canvas(top_frame,width=36,height=36
            ,bg=self['bg'],bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
        self.info_icon.create_oval(0,0,30,30,fill='#0077be',outline='#0077be')
        self.info_icon.create_text(15,16,text='i',font=('',18),fill='white')
        self.info_icon.pack(side='left',padx=(20,0),anchor='center')
        self.label=Label(top_frame,text=message,bg=self['bg'])
        self.label.pack(padx=(1,20),pady=5,anchor='center')
        self.ok_button=ttk.Button(bottom_frame,text='OK',
            state='active',command=self._destroy)
        self.ok_button.pack(anchor='e',padx=15,pady=10)
        self.update()
        center_x=self.winfo_screenwidth()//2-self.winfo_width()//2
        center_y=self.winfo_screenheight()//2-self.winfo_height()//2
        self.geometry(f'+{center_x}+{center_y}')
        self.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW',self._destroy)
        self.exists=True

    def _destroy(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.exists=False

root=Tk()

infobox=InfoBox()
button=Button(root,text='Hello',command=lambda:infobox.call('Info','Hello'))
button.pack()
button1=Button(root,text='World',command=lambda:infobox.call('Info','World'))
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. The thread works just as I wanted it to, but is there a way to delete it? because as of now, the toplevel box are stacking on each other. I would like to be able to delete one as the next one spawns.

Comment: @Y0SHI0N Are you using `Toplevel` or `messagebox` because as far as I know, closing the `messagebox` programmatically is not possible, you would have to go with `Toplevel` and create a function that checks if any toplevel info box is existing and destroy that before calling the new one.

Comment: I am using 'TopLevel' as you suggested in the second option

Comment: @Y0SHI0N I have updated the answer, this will automatically prevent stacking, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for the update. I ran it and it worked ( without any modification). However, since I really want to automate it, I need to understand how the code work, can you please explain why you coded it like that, please? It is fine if you decide not to. Sorry if it is too much to ask, I am just very new to python.

Comment: @Y0SHI0N It's alright, I can explain, but I would first suggest you to go through it and do your research (helps in better learning) and find out the parts that you have difficulty in understanding, then let me know. Apart from that by automation do you mean that you mean that you want to recall the info box from within your main code? If yes, then you can simply call `infobox._destroy()` and as an example check [this](https://pastebin.com/MaHfMewr)

Comment: @ AST Thank you for the explanation and link, also sorry for the late reply. After your help, I have managed to learn how TopLevel works to the least basic extend that I can do my assignment. Thank you so much.